# Perform an HTTP request in the background without loading webpage?

Tags: javascript, http, get

So there is this 3rd party website that contains a button that, when clicked, sends a GET request and performs some server-side task which updates the logged in user's data into its database. This desired task has to be performed on every calendar day. Is there an alternative way to making this website's server perform the task without making it load the page for each of the calendar days? The URL attached to that button seems to be using REST API because the button element has `href` URL which contains a path + arguments. Currently, my solution to making it perform that server-side task for me is to change the URL's argument and open that URL in a new browser tab.

To be more precise the url looks something like this: `https://something.com/somepath/47240/6/sort?date=2018-03-06&crumb=JMBuREVDPqS`
I discovered that simply changing the date argument to the next day and loading that URL in the browser will make this website's servers perform the desired task for the next day too. Is there a way to make it perform this task in the background without loading a separate tab for each day or is manipulating the date argument and opening that updated URL in a separate tab the only solution? Since my current method simply opens up the updated date URLs, it was implemented purely through client-side code. So I would like to know of alternative solutions using client-side code only.

Comment: Try using Ajax.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? I have not used AJAX before so maybe some sample code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Generate array of dates for which you want to call.
2. Iterate each date, and make a request to the server.
3. On completion of the request, pick next date and process it.

Following is the sample code, which you can modify according to your case.

```
  var url="https://something.com/somepath/47240/6/sort?date=";
  var date1 = new Date();
  var date2 = new Date(2018, 1, 1);
  var day;
  var between = [date1];
 //Generate the date array for which you want to run
  while(date2 <= date1) {
      day = date1.getDate()
      date1 = new Date(date1.setDate(--day));  
      between.push(date1);
  }
//Covert date to string format for passing to the request url
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    return [year, month, day].join('-');
  }

  var callPage = function (dt) {
       return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          var urlWithParam=url+ dt + "&crumb=JMBuREVDPqS";
          xhr.open('GET', urlWithParam, true);
          xhr.onload = function () {
            //Resolve the promise, so that next can be picked
             resolve();
          };

        });
      };
    //Make the call for each date.
    for (var i = 0; i < between.length; i++) {
        callPage(between[i]).then(function () {
      });
    }
```

If you are facing issue with `CROSS DOMAIN` request, you can achieve this using hidden `iframe` like following.

```js
 var url="https://something.com/somepath/47240/6/sort?date=";
  var date1 = new Date();
  var date2 = new Date(2018, 1, 1);
  var day;
  var between = [date1];
 //Generate the date array for which you want to run
  while(date2 <= date1) {
      day = date1.getDate()
      date1 = new Date(date1.setDate(--day));  
      between.push(date1);
  }
//Covert date to string format for passing to the request url
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    return [year, month, day].join('-');
  }
    
  var callPage = function (dt) {
    
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    var urlWithParam=url+ formatDate(dt) + "&crumb=JMBuREVDPqS";
    console.log("Request ->",urlWithParam);
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    iframe.src = encodeURI(urlWithParam);
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  }    
    //Make the call for each date.
    for (var i = 0; i < between.length; i++) {
        callPage(between[i]);
    }
```

[Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/4gOIVQ7xzkA4jKIMSJEr?p=preview)

Comment: Hi. I tried using this code to test it out on a sample HTML page I made. In that HTML page, I passed in the hardcoded URL for one of the dates in which that task was not performed on yet. I attached a JS function to it using `onClick` and the function got called, but after refreshing the 3rd party page, I am not seeing any changes being reflected. Also you didn't have to worry about the URL manipualtion part. I just wanted the code for making the HTTP request given the URL

Comment: Am I supposed to have `xhr.send(null)` below the `onload` block?

Comment: I have updated the answer with iframe implementation, you can check that also. it should work for you.

Comment: The iFrame one works! Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: Done. I got an error in console: `Refused to display 'url...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.` Any way to remove this error?

Comment: the website you are trying to access through iframe is not belong to your domain and X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN is coming in the header. I doubt you can avoid that, this is a security feature implemented by browser to avoid click jacking. But for your scenario you don't need any UI for the iframe so you can ignore that.

Comment: Gotcha. I was able to simply plug in your callPage function and replace `window.open()` method with a call to that function to achieve the desired outcome. So you may want to consider removing any "clutter" in your answer

Comment: window.open will open many popup if you are running it for more dates :) usability issue

Comment: Yep. I wanted to get rid of that usability issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "Put url here";
var params = 'Put Params here'
http.open("POST", [url,params].join('?'), true);
```

Comment: What is `params` used for here? You declared it but don't use it.

Comment: replace url with   url + '?' +params

Comment: i thought its common but it's not for someone

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

1) Set interval to call the function once in a day

2) The date has to be dynamically increased after calling the function each day

```
var dayInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var todayDate = new date();
 function formatDate(todayDate ) {
  var d = new Date(date),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

 if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
setInterval(function() { 
$.get("https://something.com/somepath/47240/6/sort", 
{"date":formatDate(todayDate),"crumb":"JMBuREVDPqS"},
function(response){
console.log("http request loaded in the background")'
});
 },dayInMilliseconds );
```