# Continue processing in backend if request is interrupted

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically I'm working on an application that posts huge amounts of data to web API(third party API).

I am working on nodejs to connect to MsSQL server and fetch data, process it and post it in desired format to the web API.

Scenario is: In nodejs, I have script that does the above job. It is currently initiated (or should I say triggered?) by a button on web page using axios `POST` with all necessary parameters. Eg below:

```
axios.post('/api/v1/fetch-new-labors', {
  startDate: 'somedate',
  endDate: 'someDate' 
}).then(...handles further processing & posting to api)
```

The process takes around 2-3 mins to finish. Meanwhile, if the page is refreshed, it obviously needs to restart the whole process by clicking the button.

Question: I am sure there is a way to let the process run(on serverside I presume) that takes care of fetching, processing and posting even if the client side page is refreshed/reloaded and at the same time, keep the client side informed with progressbar or `x out of y records posted` kind of thing. I thought of web sockets but I wasn't sure if there's a prefered way to achieve this. I'm not looking for the whole code/process, I am looking for someone to guide me towards overall concept/idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49126366/perform-an-http-request-in-the-background-without-loading-webpage

Comment: You can look into using web sockets for this, it sounds like the right use case. In order to handle page refreshes, you'll have to store and re-load a session ID and/or set up your server to handle re-connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Long-running jobs usually avoid using the traditional [request-response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request%E2%80%93response) cycle, opting instead for some variation of the [Pub/Sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern described below:

### Accept request, then start processing

You should respond to the user immediately with an [HTTP 202: Accepted](https://httpstatuses.com/202), signalling you accepted the request, then start the processing.

You can perform some initial checks before responding (Does the user have other jobs? Does the request pass basic validation checks?) but you should not start processing the actual long-running job before responding.

You can use a simple HTTP request to create jobs.

### Push status updates from server to subscribed clients

On page load the client *subscribes* to updates from the server.

Using [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), push server-to-client status notifications regarding the progress. Don't forget to also handle and display errors to the client.

At this point, you'll probably need a way to uniquely identify each client across refreshes. You can easily solve this by storing a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) via [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) when a user first visits your app/website. If your app requires logins, then you can use the logged-in user's ID instead.

### Check if user has already running jobs before accepting a new one

When the user refreshes you can send an initial message via WebSockets again notifying the user if he has any running jobs and what their progress is.

Based on your OP, I think you might want to disable the "Create Job" button if there's a pending job.

---

You can use other mechanisms for bidirectional server-client communication (such as [long-polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/)/[Server-sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)) if you want, although WebSockets should be the most straightforward and flexible solution.

I'd personally go for a batteries-included WebSocket library such as [socket.io](https://socket.io/).